# Will Freya automount media?

Tags: usb-drive, audio-cd, dvd

Will the forthcoming Elementary Freya automount removable media, optical discs and usb devices?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, removable media is getting auto mounted. Contrary to other OS the file manager won't popup if you insert a media. Apparently there is no option to set the *default action* for audio CDs or DVDs, like open them in VLC or sth.

Comment: This is a security conscious decision. Auto-running media exposes the potential for security breaches.